# Insert into a table two values using two "FROM" clauses

Tags: sql, ms-access, sql-insert

Is there a way to insert into a table two values using two "FROM" clauses?
I try to insert percentile values - Exposure and Awareness:

```
INSERT INTO tbReport (Exposure, Awareness) 
SELECT MAX([q_Exposure])
  FROM (SELECT TOP 30 PERCENT [q_Exposure]
  FROM tbQuestions
  WHERE q_Exposure IS NOT NULL ORDER BY [q_Exposure]),
MAX([q_Awareness])
  FROM (SELECT TOP 30 PERCENT [q_Awareness]
  FROM tbQuestions
  WHERE q_Awareness IS NOT NULL ORDER BY [q_Awareness]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am pretty sure you could not use two SELECT statements like that, you could also do something like,

```
INSERT INTO tbReport (Exposure, Awareness) 
SELECT 
    Max(tmpQ.Exposure) As MaxExpo, 
    Max(tmpQ.Awareness) As MaxAware
FROM
    (SELECT MAX([q_Exposure]) As Exposure, 0 As Awareness FROM (SELECT TOP 30 PERCENT [q_Exposure] FROM tbQuestions WHERE q_Exposure IS NOT NULL ORDER BY [q_Exposure])
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 0 As Exposure, MAX([q_Awareness]) As Awareness FROM (SELECT TOP 30 PERCENT [q_Awareness] FROM tbQuestions WHERE q_Awareness IS NOT NULL ORDER BY [q_Awareness])) As tmpQ;
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont think the syntax you mentioned will work because typical insert syntax will be:

```
INSERT INTO table_name (col_names) VALUES (col_values);
```

Give the more clear picture of what you want from the above query?

Comment: No, we can insert with different methods, nothing wrong with syntax.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you try the following code

```
INSERT INTO tbReport (Exposure, Awareness)
SELECT MAX(SELECT TOP 30 PERCENT [q_Exposure]
FROM tbQuestions
WHERE q_Exposure IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY [q_Exposure]),
MAX(SELECT TOP 30 PERCENT [q_Awareness]
FROM tbQuestions
WHERE q_Awareness IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY [q_Awareness]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try to run the below query, hope it works :)

```
INSERT INTO tbReport (Exposure, Awareness) 
 VALUES
 (
  (SELECT MAX (Q_E.q_Exposure) 
  FROM (SELECT TOP 30 PERCENT q_Exposure FROM tbQuestions WHERE q_Exposure IS NOT NULL ORDER BY q_Exposure) Q_E)
 ,
  (SELECT  MAX(Q_A.q_Awareness) 
  FROM (SELECT TOP 30 PERCENT q_Awareness FROM tbQuestions WHERE q_Awareness IS NOT NULL ORDER BY q_Awareness) Q_A)
 )
```

I tried to simulate the same and it worked perfectly fine for me.

FYR,
I have created a table [t_empSalary]

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO

 CREATE TABLE t_empSalary
     (
     empSalary INT,
     empid INT
     )

GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
```

Please find the below screenshot

[image]

```
 INSERT INTO [t_empSalary](empSalary, empid ) VALUES 
  (
  (SELECT MAX(t_empSalary.empSalary) FROM (SELECT TOP 30 PERCENT empSalary FROM  [dbo].[t_empSalary]) t_empSalary)
   ,
  (SELECT MAX(t_emp.empid) FROM  (SELECT TOP 30 PERCENT empid FROM  [dbo].[t_empSalary]) t_emp)
  )
```